# Best way to convert object into array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object literal of following syntax:

```
const loader = {
    "0": "b",
    "1": "a",
    "2": "r",
    // arbitrary extra fields:
    "foo": 123,
    "quux": 456,
}
```

I want to convert it into array `["b", "a", "r"]` and then into string `"bar"`, which is my final goal. I don't need any extra fields, if any, and can safely discard them.

It was tempting to use `Array.from(loader)`, yet unfortunately `Array.from` expects `length` attribute to be present, which I don't have.

Given that object literal key order is not guaranteed in my case, this is the cleanest solution I've came up with so far:

```
function convert(obj) {
    const a = [];
    for (const k in obj) {
        a[k] = obj[k];
    }
    return a.join('');
}
```

Though I don't like it and it seems rather redundant and inelegant for me. Is there anything I might miss? I'm free to use anything from ES6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert an array of the object and take joined values as string.

```js
var loader = { 0: "b", 1: "a", 2: "r", foo: 123, quux: 456 },
    string = Object.assign([], loader).join('');
    
console.log(string);
```

Comment: Values as items, others as properties. Excellent !

Comment: This! This is the way to go. Clean and fast.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys`, `filter`, `map` and `join`

```
var output = Object.keys( loader ) //get the keys
              .filter( s => !isNaN( s ) ) //remove non-numeric keys
              .map( s => loader[s] ) //get values for filtered keys
              .join( "" ); //join them
```

If the keys needs to be sorted explicitly, then

```
var output = Object.keys( loader ) //get the keys
              .filter( s => !isNaN( s ) ) //remove non-numeric keys
              .sort( ( a, b ) => a - b );
              .map( s => loader[s] ) //get values for filtered keys
              .join( "" ); //join them
```

Comment: But wait... Object keys are not guaranteed to exist in a particular order. Don't you also need some kind of `.sort` as well?

Comment: keys who are possible keys of an array are sorted first by default.

Comment: yep, I shared second snippet in case it needs to be explicitly sorted if the keys were not given in order.

Answer (score 1):

Using `isNaN` gets only those ones, that are numbers. `sort` will order your `keys` in the output array and then accessing via that keys you can get the values from the `loader` object via `reduce` or just use `map` and then `join`.

```js
const loader = {
    "0": "b",
    "1": "a",
    "2": "r",
    // arbitrary extra fields:
    "foo": 123,
    "quux": 456,
};

const obj = Object.keys(loader).filter(key => !isNaN(key))
                  .sort()
                  .map(key => loader[key])
                  .join('');
                   
console.log(obj);
```